# Redirect /index.php from the end of the URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, canonicalization

Have a website with subpages all in this format:

```
mydomain.com/something
```

That's fine. But what is NOT fine is that you can **also** do `mydomain.com/something/index.php` (you can enter address in this format into your browser) and you still get the content on that `mydomain.com/something`.

I don't want those two possibilites to be available at the same time, Google doesn't like this. I want just one to be possible.

So what I want to do is whenever you type into your browser `mydomain.com/something/index.php`, you will be redirected to `mydomain.com/something` (without that `/index.php` at the end).

How should I write a .htaccess code to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following lines to .htaccess in the root directory of your website

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

Note: the first condition assure that no previous redirection is made (to prevent redirection loop)

Comment: what other rules do you have in  your .htaccess, there must be some conflit.

Comment: Only `www` to `non-www` redirect, oh plus this

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz)$ index.php [L]`

Comment: Oh yes, now your solution works when I remove lines above (that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f ...`, but unfortunatelly then mydomain.com/something makes that /something page a 404 - I need that previous lines there, can't remove them...

Comment: add the code in my answer before those directives, that should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Mordor:

You can try this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your solution makes `mydomain.com/anything/index.php` goes to homepage, to `mydomain.com` which is not what my heart desires. I need it to go to `mydomain.com/anything` (so basically all I need is that `/index.php` to be "escaped")